# SceneKit SCNAction.run and rotation not working

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a scene with a box that should run a rotation action forever:

`dps` is a property that could be changed by user.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
        self.rateScene.scene = scene

        let actionwait = SCNAction.wait(duration: 0.001)
        let run = SCNAction.run {_ in
            let fps = 60.0
            let delta = (self.dps*3.14/180.0)/fps
            self.boxNode.rotation.z -= CGFloat(delta)
        }
        let moveSequence = SCNAction.sequence([actionwait, run])
        let forever = SCNAction.repeatForever(moveSequence)
        boxNode.runAction(forever)

    }
```

Variable `self.boxNode.rotation.z` - changes every time, but the box doesn't rotate.

Comment: Isn't this SceneKit instead of SpriteKit?

Comment: @jjs, yes, but the problem area, the closure used to define the activity of the custom action, is probably the exact same problem one would have in SpriteKit.

Comment: @arti where'd you get the inspiration to create a custom action like this? I'm genuinely curious for personal reasons. I like the way you're thinking about this, and want to do something similar.

Comment: what's the `w` value for `rotation`? (i.e. you're setting a rotation axis, but is the angle non-null?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wont work because the SCNAction.run is just evaluated once. You have to reassign the action every time you change the value.

What you could do is something like that. Simply put that code in the IBAction of your slider (or whatever the user uses to control the value)

```
let fps = 60.0
let delta = (self.dps * 3.14 / 180.0) / fps

SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.1
boxNode.rotation.z -= Float(delta)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping a DPS property on the scene or scene's owner, and use a `didSet` on the DPS? The `didSet` will reset the rotation, something like:

```
let radiansPerSecond = M_PI / 180.0 * dps
let rotate = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0.0, y: 0, z: radiansPerSecond, duration: 1.0))
boxNode.runAction(rotate)
```

The DPS change can be caught within 1 second and your action gets restarted with the new rotation rate. And you don't have to set a new  `SCNAction` 60 times per second.